# Extract users through arcgis python api (query='*', max_users='*')

Tags: arcgis

Every time I run this code with a wild card (max_users = '*') or >140 I get this error JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0).

```
def datetime_of_last_login(user) -> dt.datetime:
    timestamp_of_last_login = int(user.lastLogin / 1000)
    last_login = dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp_of_last_login)
    return last_login

def num_days_since_last_login(user) -> int:
        last_login = datetime_of_last_login(user)
        now = dt.datetime.now()
        return (now - last_login).days
       
users = gis.users.search(query='*', max_users=140)

for user in users:
    cd = dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(user.created / 1000).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    last_login_datetime = datetime_of_last_login(user)
    days_since_last_login = num_days_since_last_login(user)
    print("_____________________________________________________________")
    print(f"User: {user.username}")
    print(f"Role: {user.role}")
    print(f"Email: {user.email}")
    print("Creation Date:", cd)
    print("Last Login:", last_login_datetime)
    print("Days Since Last Login:", days_since_last_login)
```

when the value is <140e it works fine not just all the users are returned. Also, try an exception and still get same result.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong.